# Gradient estimates of linear elliptic PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded smooth domain. Assume that $u(x)$ is the classical solution solving
$$a_{ij}(x)\partial_{ij}u(x)+b_i(x)\partial_iu(x)+c(x)u(x)=f(x)$$
$$u(x)\Big|_{\partial \Omega}=g(x)$$
for some smooth enough coefficients and uniformly elliptic $a_{ij}$. I found that in Gilbarg and Trudinger's PDE book, Theorem 8.33 states that
$$ |u|_{1,\alpha,\Omega'}\leq C(|u|_{0}+|g|_{0}+|f|_{0,\alpha}) $$
for $\Omega' \subset \Omega$ and some constant $C$ depending on the $C^{0,\alpha}$-norms of $a_{ij}$, $b_i$ and $c$ (and some other parameters).

Now, I am looking for a upper bound of $|\nabla u|$ on $\Omega'$, not the holder norm, can this upper be something like
$$ \sup_{\Omega'}|u|\leq C(|u|_{0}+|g|_{0}+|f|_{0}) $$
for some constant $C$ depending on the $C^{0}$-norms of $a_{ij}$, $b_i$ and $c$, but not their holder norms? If this is to complicated, we can deal with the ODE case or equation in divergence form.

Comment: Have you tried using a [numerical method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations)? You could also see systems theory for time-varying second order systems.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment! I do not know much about the numerical thing so I haven't try it.

Comment: Do you mean $\sup_{\Omega'}|\nabla u|$ in your last equation? Also if $|\nabla u|$ has bounded $C^\alpha$ norm, wouldn't it mean its sup is bounded, if you know the value at one point? So issue seems to be if you can bound $|\nabla u|$ at one point, to me.

Comment: @Threeaggies yes, but the holder norm of the gradient is found to depend on the holder norm of the coefficients. I want to have the upper bound of the sup norm of the gradient depends only on the sup norm of the coefficients.